# xscreensaver - how to log successful logins

Tags: logs, login, xscreensaver

I would like to log successful login attempts from screensaver.

Running xscreensaver with `xscreensaver -verbose -log ...`
does give me something usable:

```
input finished.
    pam_conversation (...) ==> PAM_SUCCESS
  pam_authenticate (...) ==> 0 (Success)
  pam_acct_mgmt (...) ==> 0 (Success)
  pam_setcred (...) ==> 0 (Success)
pam_end (...) ==> 0 (Success)
```

But I'd like to have a line in authlog, similar to what one sees on failed login attempts.

I've tried configuring /etc/pam.d/xscreensaver, but I'm too ignorant at the moment.

Comment: So you want to log **UN**successful login attempts, not successful logins (as the title now implies)? As in someone was guessing your password the whole time you were away?

Comment: @Xen2050 no, the UNsuccessful login attempts are already logged. I want to log successful logins (when the xscreensaver unlock is successful), that at the moment are ignored